# Error inserting module: Device or resource busy

Tags: rhel, drivers, kernel-modules, modprobe, oracle-linux

When running modprobe to insert a module into kerner I get the following:

```
# modprobe 8192cu
FATAL: Error inserting 8192cu (/lib/modules/3.8.13-118.2.1.el6uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192.cu.ko): Device or resource busy
```

This happens both when the device is plugged in and not. It may be also related to other errors that I see when trying to reinstall the driver:

```
# rmmod 8192.cu.ko
ERROR: Module 8192cu does not exist in /proc/modules
# insmod 8192.cu.ko
insmod: error inserting `8192cu.ko`: -1 Device or resource busy
```

The strangest is that the device is not even plugged in. It worked well until my Oracle Linux (based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6) was restarted.

How should I reinstall the driver and make sure it works correctly?

```
# dmesg
rtl8192cu driver version=v4.0.2_9000.20130911
build time: Dec 2 2015 15:05:23
Error: Driver 'rtl8192cu' is already registered, aborting...
```

Comment: problem solved using appraoch above, thanks! the device is now registered again and no longer busy, I should write a script to automate this at every reboot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the module `rtl8192cu` is already loaded and this prevents `8192cu` to load. So, first unload that module:

```
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
```

Now, you can load the new one:

```
modprobe 8192cu
```

If it works you can blacklist the first module. To blacklist a module and thus preventing the loading during bootup use this command:

```
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf
```

After a reboot, the system should not have the old module loaded.

Comment: The part with the bootup still not working (have to do these steps manually), but it may as well be something else not working...

Comment: `lsmod | grep 8192` shows that `rtl8192cu` is being present right after booting

Comment: didn't you mean `echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf`?

Comment: right, you have to change `echo "blacklist 8192cu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-8192cu.conf` to `echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rtl8192cu.conf` and then it works right after reboot

Comment: @PeterGerhat Yes, sure I meant that, sorry, was a typo. Will correct it in the answer.